# h6 element takes more space than it should

Tags: html, css

I have just a simple h6 tag and it just takes a lot of space for no reason. This is the code I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="logintitle">
  <h6>LOGIN</h6>
</div>
```

First attempt in CSS

```
.logintitle {
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
border: 1px solid black; /* showing unwanted margin top and bottom */
}
```

The following gives me the below result:
[image]

Comment: you can change style of `h6` using CSS

Comment: What's the `line-height`? Does it have `margin` or `padding`?

Comment: i tried to set margin and padding to 0 as well but it does nothing, I didnt set line height

Comment: Open the dev tools of you browser. And show please the CSS applied to h6 element. Some styles can be inherited or applied.

Comment: @Fox is probably right. The `h6` is probably inheriting styles from something more specific.

Comment: It inherited font from body and font size from body

Comment: It's also inherited either a lot of padding or a large line-height from something else in your CSS.

Comment: In layout I noticed it has 50px margin on top and bottom,

Comment: @crodev well, now you need only to override those styles for h6 element.

Comment: ok thanks thats it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All heading tags (like your `<h6>`) by default have some amount of top and bottom margin to them. Additionally, if you have other styles in your project, they may be adding more.

If you do not want those margins, you can do this, which should likely fix your issue:

```
.logintitle h6 { margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error in the class name, you have to add "h6" to the class name.

TRY:

```
.logintitle h6{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   line-height:16px;
   font-size:14px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an additional note, if you want to reset margin and padding on all the elements of your site, you can use the following CSS reset:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Also, worthy of mention, is the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) CSS property, which -in the following reset- sets all your elements' sizes to include border and padding:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```